# Disabling Submit Button On Click Does not Submit Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to prevent double submission of a form, and in doing so, I am disabling the submit button after the initial click.  To accomplish this, I have added the following javascript to my page:

```
var $loginSubmitBtn = $('#loginSubmitBtn');
$loginSubmitBtn.click(function () {
    $loginSubmitBtn.prop('disabled', true);
});
```

This is having the undesired effect of disabling the button before the Post can be executed to submit the form.  Is there a way to ensure the Post gets through prior to the button being disabled?

Comment: Try listening to the `submit` event of your form instead of the `click` on your submit button.

Comment: Try adding a `return true;` in the function.

Comment: @AlonAlexander is there a reason I should be adding return true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of disabling the button after a `click` on it, disable it after your form's `submit` :

```
var $loginSubmitBtn = $('#loginSubmitBtn');

$('#yourForm').on('submit', function() {
  $loginSubmitBtn.prop('disabled', true);
});
```